Fourier transform of periodic distributions
Let $f$ is a tempered distribution, i.e., $f \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$, and is periodic with period $2\pi$, then $T_{2\pi k} f = f$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^d$, here $T_{v}$ is translation by $v \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Hence we know that its Fourier transform is supported on the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$.
Question: I want to conclude that there exists a sequence ${a_n}$ such that
$$
    \hat{f} = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d} a_n \delta_n
$$
My Attempts:
My first attempt is try to use the characterization of distributions supported on a single point. If a tempered distribution is supported at one point $x_0$, then we can write $f$ as $f = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq N} c_\alpha \partial^{\alpha} \delta_{x_0}$. For this specific case, I want to consider $\chi f$, where $\chi$ is a suitable compactly supported function in a small neighbourhood of each $\mathbb{Z}^d$. But, how can we get rid of the derivatives?
My second attempt is to try prove it directly. I still consider a suitable $\chi$ similar to the previous one, then let $\phi$ to be a Schwartz function,
\begin{equation*}
    \langle\hat{f},\phi\rangle = \langle\hat{f},\phi - \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \chi_k\phi(k)\rangle + \langle 
\hat{f}, \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \chi_k\phi(k) \rangle,
\end{equation*}
where $\chi_k$ is such suitable $\chi$ near each $k \in \mathbb{Z}^d$. I think, by the linearity and the fact that $\hat{f}$ is supported on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, the first term is $0$, and hence we get the result, where $a_n = \langle \hat{f}, \chi_k \rangle$. But my question is that how can we show this $a_n$ is the same for all test functions. i.e., is it possible to find one such $\chi$ that works for all test functions?

Let's focus on $x_0=0$ for simplicity. The proof that $\hat f$ has support in $\Bbb Z^d$ can be extended to show that not only is $\hat f$ supported in $\Bbb Z^d$, but actually near $x_0$ we have $\xi_j \hat f = 0$ for $j=1,\dots, d$. And this implies that near $x_0$ $\hat f$ must be a multiple of $\delta_0$ without any derivatives.
Details: From $T_{2\pi k}f=f$ we get $e^{2\pi i\langle k,\xi\rangle}\hat f=\hat f$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$, or $(e^{2\pi i\langle k,\xi\rangle}-1)\hat f=0$. Let $k=e_j$. Then near $0$ we have $e^{2\pi i\langle k,\xi\rangle}-1=2\pi i\xi_j+O(|\xi_j|^2)$, so $\xi_j\chi \hat f = 0$ where $\chi$ is $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$ and has small support around $0$. Now let $\phi$ be a test function with support contained in set where $\chi=1$. Then $\phi=\chi\phi$. We can write $\phi=\phi(0)+\sum_{j=1}^d\xi_j\phi_j$ with other functions $\phi_j$ also with support in the set where $\chi=1$. Then we get $$\langle \hat f, \phi\rangle = \langle \hat f, \chi\phi\rangle=\phi(0)\langle \hat f,\chi\rangle + \sum_{j=1}^d\langle \hat f, \chi\xi_j\phi_j\rangle$$
Now $\langle \hat f, \chi\xi_j\phi_j\rangle = \langle \xi_j\chi\hat f, \phi_j\rangle =0$. So $\langle\chi\hat f,\phi\rangle$ only depends on the value of $\phi$ (and not its derivatives) at $0$, so $\hat f\rvert_{U}=c\delta_0$ where $c$ is a constant and $U$ is a small neighborhood of $0$ (here for example a subset where $\chi=1$).

Thank you so much for your answer, I really get something!

I like the other answer very much, especially because I would have never thought of following that approach. I like to think of distributions as limits of sequences of functions, in appropriate topologies. Distributions retain those properties of functions that commute with such limits.

Let us now answer the question following the method sketched above. Suppose we are given the $2\pi$-periodic tempered distribution $f\in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^d)$. Then there is a sequence of $2\pi$-periodic continuous functions $f_k$ such that $f_k\to f$ in $\mathcal S'$. For each $k$, we can develop $f_k$ in Fourier series:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Fourier_series}
    f_k(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^d} \frac{a_{nk}}{(2\pi)^d} e^{in\cdot x}. 
\end{equation}
The identity $\mathcal F[e^{ix\cdot n}]_{x\to \xi}=(2\pi)^d\delta(n-\xi)^{[1]}$ now implies the following formula for the Fourier transform:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:cont_Fourier_transform}\tag{1}
    \widehat{f_k}(\xi)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z^d} a_{nk} \delta(n-\xi). 
\end{equation}
Remark. We have proved that $\widehat{f_k}$ is a Dirac comb, which is exactly what we want to show for the tempered distribution $f$. It is now time to extend this result via a limiting argument.
By assumption, $\widehat{f_k}\to \widehat{f}$ in $\mathcal S'$. Which means that $\langle \widehat{f_k}, \phi\rangle\to \langle \widehat{f}, \phi\rangle$ for each $\phi\in \mathcal S$. A fortiori, the same holds for $\phi$ of compact support, i.e. $\phi\in \mathcal D$, in which case
$$
\langle \widehat{f_k}, \phi\rangle=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^d\cap \mathrm{Supp }\,\phi} a_{nk}\phi(n),$$
which is just a finite sum. Since we know it converges, and $\phi$ is arbitrary, it must be that each number $a_{nk}$ converges to a number $a_n$. We conclude that
$$
\widehat{f_k}(\xi)\to \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^d} a_n \delta(\xi-n)$$
in the sense of $\mathcal D'$. Since $\mathcal S'\subset \mathcal D'$, and $\widehat{f_k}\to \widehat{f}$ in $\mathcal S'$, uniqueness of limits yields
$$
\widehat{f}(\xi)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^d} a_n\delta(\xi-n), $$
as we wanted to prove.

[1] I computed this via the formal identity $\int_{\mathbb R^d} e^{ix\cdot \eta}\, dx=(2\pi)^d\delta(\eta)$, which is very useful in practice.
